# How to automatically restart the service when crush on CentOS?

Tags: linux, docker, service, centos

I have a docker service on centos, and I found that the docker service will crush in sometimes.

I have to run the command `service docker start` manually.

So how to watch the service and automatically restart when the services crush?

Thank you!

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/252162/483130

Answer (score 1):

yes! use `monit`. Seems work

```
check process docker with pidfile /var/run/docker.pid
    start program = "/bin/systemctl start docker"
    stop program = "/bin/systemctl stop docker"
```